# What algebraic properties are preserved by $\mathbb{N}\leadsto\beta\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, gn.general-topology, model-theory, universal-algebra

Given a binary operation $\star$ on $\mathbb{N}$, we can naturally extend $\star$ to a semicontinuous operation $\widehat{\star}$ on the set $\beta\mathbb{N}$ of ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$ as follows:

$$\mathcal{U}\mathbin{\widehat \star}\mathcal{W}:=\{A:\{k: \{a: a\star k\in A\}\in\mathcal{U}\}\in\mathcal{W}\}.$$

It's a standard (and [quite useful!](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Hindman.pdf)) fact that associativity is preserved under this transformation: if $\star$ is associative, then so is $\widehat{\star}$. On the other hand, commutativity [is *not* preserved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87109/addition-on-ultrafilters-is-non-commutative). Say that an equational sentence $\sigma$ involving a single binary function symbol is a **$\beta$-property** iff we have $$(\mathbb{N};\star)\models\sigma\quad\implies\quad (\beta\mathbb{N};\widehat{\star})\models\sigma$$ for every binary operation $\star$ on $\mathbb{N}$.

> **Question**: Which equational sentences are $\beta$-properties?

Of course there is no need to restrict attention to equational properties per se *(which is why I've used "$\implies$" rather than "$\iff$" in the definition of $\beta$-property)*, and we can similarly transform arbitrarily many arbitrary-arity operations on $\mathbb{N}$; however, already this question seems difficult. I recall seeing a partial(?) answer to this question which involved the way variables were/were not *reordered* in the left vs. right hand sides of $\sigma$, but at the moment I can't track it down.

---

Incidentally, the following question is at least of a related *flavor*, and may involve relevant ideas (and be easier to tackle at first): what is $(\beta\mathbb{N};\widehat{+})$ *(or $(\beta\mathbb{Z};\widehat{+})$ using the analogous definition)* like from a universal-algebraic perspective? For example, is it congruence modular?

Comment: Notice also many quasiidentities like cancellativity are not preserved.

Comment: There are some results  in Hindman's book on conditions guaranteeing the Stone-Cech compactification of a semigroup contains a free semigroup on 2 generators and hence satisfies no semigroup identity.  If is of course possible for the original semigroup to satisfy an identity and so this identity is not preserved. Commutativity is such and identity and so are Malcev's nilpotent identities.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Is that book [*Algebra in the Stone-Cech compactification*](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110258356/html?lang=en)?

Comment: Yes.  I think chapter 6 talks about free subsemigroups.  Of course it doesn't looks at nonassociative magmas.  My impression is that few general semigroup identities are  preserved.

Comment: One thing that is preserved of course is either xy=x or xy=y

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg xy=zw is also preserved. :P