# Ultrafilter subtraction and "zero"

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, gn.general-topology, universal-algebra, ultrafilters

*This is related to a couple recent MO/MSE questions of mine, namely [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/427135/what-algebraic-properties-are-preserved-by-mathbbn-leadsto-beta-mathbbn),[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4498457/which-ultrafilters-are-sort-of-commutators). Belatedly, I've tweaked this post to remove an overly-ambitious secondary question; see the edit history if interested.*

Let $\beta\mathbb{Z}$ be the set of all ultrafilters on $\mathbb{Z}$, and as usual conflate $n$ and $\{A\subseteq\mathbb{Z}:n\in A\}$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. We can extend any binary operation on $\mathbb{Z}$ to a semicontinuous analogue on $\beta\mathbb{Z}$, at the cost of many (most?) algebraic properties. Ultrafilter *addition* is quite well studied (see e.g. [Hindman/Strauss](https://people.dm.unipi.it/dinasso/ULTRA2015/BUMN/Hindman_Strauss%20-%20Algebra%20in%20the%20Stone-Cech%20compactification%20(2012%20-%202nd%20ed).pdf)), but I've been able to find much less about ultrafilter *subtraction*: $$\mathcal{U}\widehat{-}\mathcal{W}=\{A\subseteq\mathbb{Z}: \{k:\{a: a-k\in A\}\in\mathcal{U}\}\in\mathcal{W}\}.$$

Say that an ultrafilter $\mathcal{W}$ is **zeroid** iff $\mathcal{W}=\mathcal{U}\widehat{-}\mathcal{U}$ for some $\mathcal{U}$. My question is:

> Which ultrafilters are zeroid?

To make this actually answerable, I tentatively guess that $(i)$ $0$ is the only zeroid principle ultrafilter but not the only zeroid ultrafilter and $(ii)$ $p$-points are not zeroid; are these guesses true?

Comment: What about the “other” obvious subtraction, viꝫ. $\mathcal{U}\mathbin{\widetilde{-}}\mathcal{W} := \{A\subseteq\mathbb{Z}: \{k:\{a: k-a\in A\}\in\mathcal{W}\}\in\mathcal{U}\}$ (or, if you will, $(-\mathcal{W})\mathbin{\widehat{-}}(-\mathcal{U})$)? Doesn't it make sense to ask similar questions about it?

Comment: (My point being: since addition on $\mathbb{Z}$ is commutative, there is only one way to pass to ultrafilters, although we get a non-commutative operation. But since subtraction on $\mathbb{Z}$ is non-commutative, we need to choose the order in which we “ultrafilterize” the arguments, giving *a priori* two different operations on the ultrafilters. I have no idea whether they are the same, or similar, or very different.)

Comment: PS: Just an unimportant LaTeX/MathJAX point: when decorating a binary operation like `\widehat{-}`, you should wrap `\mathbin{...}` around it so as to give it proper spacing wrt its arguments: `X\mathbin{\widehat{-}}Y` produces $X\mathbin{\widehat{-}}Y$ which is nicer than `X\widehat{-}Y` giving $X\widehat{-}Y$.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen, actually commutativity doesn't help. The two ways of extending addition are different.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen, for one choice all left translations are continuous for the other all right. Only for principal ultrafilters are both translations continuous. This can be found in Hindman and Strauss Algebra in the Stone Cech compactification

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I agree that you get two different operations if you pass to the limit on the right operand first or on the left operand first; but if the initial operation was commutative (as for $+$ on $\mathbb{Z}$), the two different opreations $\widehat{+}$ and $\widetilde{+}$ are just the same with order of operands exchanged: $p\mathbin{\widetilde{+}}q=q\mathbin{\widehat{+}}p$. Whereas if it's not, as for $-$, we get two genuinely different operations which *a priori* can act very differently and satisfy different identities. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Gro-Tsen they are the same once you switch the order  for commutative semigroups.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Right, so that's what I was saying: for addition we get the same operation in either case, up to the order of the operands, whereas for subtraction we get two *genuinely different* operations.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen, that's fine.  I was objecting to the order of operations not being mentioned

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both your guesses are correct. To see this, it's helpful to reformulate the way you're thinking about the subtraction operator on $\beta \mathbb Z$. Beginning with subtraction on $\mathbb Z$, you can first extend this to an operator $\beta \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \rightarrow \beta \mathbb Z$ by setting $\mathcal U - n = \{B-n :\, B \in \mathcal U\} = \{A \subseteq \mathbb Z :\, A+n \in \mathcal U\}$. Notice that this agrees with your definition of subtraction on $\beta \mathbb Z$ when we identify $n$ with the principle ultrafilter at $n$. So this is the "right" way to think of subtracting an integer from an ultrafilter. But then there is only one way to extend this to a semi-continuous operation $\beta \mathbb Z \times \beta \mathbb Z$: we must define $$\mathcal U - \mathcal W = \textstyle {\mathcal W}\text{-}\!\lim_n (\mathcal U-n).$$ This again agrees with your definition (it must!), but personally I find it much more intuitive to think of $\mathcal U - \mathcal W$ as a topological limit of the sequence $\mathcal U, \mathcal U - 1, \mathcal U - 2, \dots$.

This description of what's going on makes your two guesses plainly true. For $(i)$, note that if $\mathcal U$ is nonprincipal then so is $\mathcal U - n$ for all $n$, which means (because $\mathbb Z$ is open in $\beta \mathbb Z$) that the limit ${\mathcal W}\text{-}\!\lim_n (\mathcal U-n)$ is in $\beta Z \setminus \mathbb Z$ for any $\mathcal W$ (including $\mathcal W = \mathcal U$). For $(ii)$, note that ${\mathcal W}\text{-}\!\lim_n (\mathcal U-n)$ is a limit of a countable sequence of points in $\beta \mathbb Z \setminus \mathbb Z$, hence not a P-point. In fact, let me observe that $\mathcal U - \mathcal W$ is never a weak P-point (for the same reason), which shows that not every ultrafilter is representable as the difference of two others.

Comment: I've cut Q2 so this fully answers my question. Belatedly, thanks very much!